Node.js unable to find command prompt in VS Code powershell terminal
I was trying to run sanity backend using npm run dev in VS Code and this error shows up. Note that by mistake I had deleted one environment variable from the system variables list and saved it without knowing its consequences.
PS C:\Users\SAGAR DEEP\Desktop\portf\fullportfolio\studio-sanity-backend> npm run dev

> sanity-backend@1.0.0 dev
> sanity dev

Error: Error while obtaining machine id: Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at C:\Users\SAGAR DEEP\Desktop\portf\fullportfolio\studio-sanity-backend\node_modules\node-machine-id\dist\index.js:1:7964
    at exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:442:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Unhandled rejection: Error: Error while obtaining machine id: Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at C:\Users\SAGAR DEEP\Desktop\portf\fullportfolio\studio-sanity-backend\node_modules\node-machine-id\dist\index.js:1:7964
    at exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:442:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

I was able to run the backend part using my system Command Prompt and it should look like this:
C:\Users\SAGAR DEEP\Desktop\portf\fullportfolio\studio-sanity-backend>npm run dev

> sanity-backend@1.0.0 dev
> sanity dev

✅ Checking configuration files...
Sanity Studio using vite@4.5.5 ready in 2997ms and running at http://localhost:3333/

I tried many methods like -

Adding cmd path location  C:\Windows\System32  into user and system environment paths. That didn't work
Trying using system restore which is not possible as I didn't turn on system protection before the issue arised.
Using echo $PATH to find all paths and paste them into my env path variables.
Go to registry editor and check for old path variables in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SYSTEM>ControlSet001>Control>Session Manager>Environment>Path
As a last ditch effort I tried finding cmd using where cmd and it failed too.

Here is how my system paths look like currently-
C:\Windows\System32;

F:\Anaconda\Library\bin;

F:\Anaconda\Scripts;

F:\PythonFolder\python.exe;

%SystemRoot%\system32;

%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;

